# How to make a nav menu fade in with js? It pops out from a hamburger icon and I want it to fade in on open and out on close

Tags: javascript, transition, fadein, navbar, fade

jQuery is not available here, only jQuery lite. i dont have much experience with js, so thats kinda where i need the help.

i have a navbar on a global header. when it goes to mobile breakpoints, it becomes a hamburger icon. when you click the icon a list pops out, and i want that pane to fade in and out.

there is existing js code that toggles the menu to open and close, and is tied to an anchor tag in the html. the html is tied to angular and some jsp's and is a bit messy, so i'd rather keep it simple and code the fade into the js toggle function. which looks like:

```
ctrl.toggleMobileProfileMenu = function () {
    if (viewport.isMobile()){
        if (!$scope.mobileProfileMenuOpen){

    // insert fadein code here, such as
            $scope.menuFadeIn();

            $scope.mobileProfileMenuOpen = true;
            ctrl.getBodyElement().addClass('hide-overflow');
        } else {

   // insert fade out code here, such as...
           $scope.menuFadeOut();

            $scope.mobileProfileMenuOpen = false;
            ctrl.getBodyElement().removeClass('hide-overflow');
        }
        $scope.mobileNavMenuOpen = false;
    }
};
```

i was thinking about creating a helper function like

```
  ctrl.fadeMenuIn = function () {
         var el = $window.getElementById('mobile-menu');
         el.style.transition = "all 1s ease-in;"
         el.style.opacity = 1;
  };
```

or is this better:

```
  ctrl.fadeMenuIn = function () {
         $('.menu-page-class').css("transition", "all 1s ease-in");
         $('.menu-page-class').css("opacity", 1);
  };
```

and then another for the fade out.

am i going in the right direction here for doing this only with js? i had tried transition properties on the html elements but due to how thats laid out (long story short), this is an easier and more direct implementation becaue the toggleMobileNavMenu() function is called from a seperate jsp.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are going in a right direction, obviously there are a lot of space for improvements.

I would recommend adding a prefixed classes, like `js-mobile-menu` to identify elements, affected by your JavaScript.

I doubt if you  really need to extend the `ctrl` object with those functions, but that's up to you.

Consider using [CSS transition](http://CSS%20transition) to make the opacity animation smoother.

Comment: do you mean instead of giving them IDs and using getElementById?

Comment: @heug it's not critical in any way, you might keep the ID if you want, I think it's just nice to let people know that you're using JavaSript on specific elements. Having and id attribute and using getElementById has some benefits, it's the fastest selector you might use. Also, I don't know what version of jQuery Lite you're using, but as far as I know, it still suppotrs SIzzle selector engine, so you probably can use `$('.foo')` for DOM interactions.